# how to set rtl on TabContainer ajaxToolkit?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I use ajaxToolkit 4.5 in vs2012.i want TabContainer in myapp set to  rtl.
I use float="right" or dir="rtl" but not work.
Please Help.

```
 <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" ID="Tabs" Height="138px" OnClientActiveTabChanged="ActiveTabChanged" 
                ActiveTabIndex="2" Width="402px">
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="Panel1" HeaderText="Signature and Bio" dir="rt>......
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style rule on your page: `.ajax__tab_container { direction: rtl; }`